# Negative Binomial with $4$ white faces before $3$ black faces

Tags: probability, combinatorics, negative-binomial

Suppose that a fair $6$-sided die having $2$ black faces and $4$ white faces will be rolled repeatedly. What is the probability that $4$ rolls resulting in a white face occur before $3$ rolls resulting in a black face?

**Attemped Solution:**

I'm trying to make use of the following negative binomial formula:

$n$ trials, given $k$ success: ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$$p^k$$(1-p)^{n-k}$

In our case, $n$ can be $4,5$, or $6$ and $k$ is fixed at $4$.

$3\choose{3}$$(\frac{2}{3})$$^4$(${1}\over{3}$)$^0$+$4\choose3$(${2}\over{3}$)$^4$(${1}\over{3}$)+$5\choose3$(${2}\over{3}$)$^4$(${1}\over{3}$)$^2$ = $.680$

Is this a valid solution? I would also be interested in alternative solutions.

Comment: do you mean four/three consecutive rolls?

Comment: No, 4 white rolls total occurs before getting 3 black rolls total.

Comment: Example: WWWBBW, WWBWBW

Comment: Actually, the idea is that out of the first 6 rolls, at least 4 should be white (because otherwise you have at least 3 black, and less than 4 white). So think about the meaning of your $n$ and $k$

Comment: But don't you stop after you get 4 whites before 3 black? For example, WBWWWW isn't in the event space?

Comment: it doesn't hurt to continue, what happens after will not affect your odds, because WBWWWB is also in the accepted winning combos

Comment: Ah yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: They give the same result, so I guess yours is also good; basically you are adding up the probabilities that the 4th white will be exactly on the 4th, 5th,or 6th roll

Comment: Mind sharing your method?

Comment: Gotcha so on the 5th it would be $4\choose{3}$$(2/3)^3$$1/3$?

Comment: Because you'd have to get 3 whites in the first 4 rolls and then a white on the 5th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

What your solution is doing is adding up the probabilities that the 4th white roll will be **exactly** the 4th, 5th, or 6th roll, respectively. For the $k$-th white roll to be the $n$-th overall, in the previous $n-1$ you must have $k-1$ whites exactly, that's why you are doing binomial with $n-1$ and $k-1$, but then you have to multiply by an extra $2/3$ for the actual $n$-th roll being white, and you get your formula. The possibilities for $n$ are 4, 5, and 6, because the 7th roll would be too late, already failed.

You can also proceed like this: to have 4 whites before 3 blacks is the same as to have at least 4 whites among the first 6 rolls: if it happens, you have 4 whites before (at most) 2 blacks, and if it doesn't, then you have at least 3 blacks and no more than 3 whites in these first 6 rolls, so you have failed.

So it's just standard binomial with $n=6$ and $4 \leq k \leq 6$:
$$\sum_{k=4}^{6} \binom{6}{k} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{6-k} = \frac{31\cdot 2^4}{3^6} $$

Comment: Standard binomial makes much more sense to me than negative binomial.